# macOS High Sierra Calendar notifications appear but have the wrong event time

Tags: macos, calendar, notifications

I have a (recurring) meeting notice in my calendar.  On my iPhone and on macOS I get the (half-an-hour before) alert, but they display differently!  On my iPhone it is displayed as "Meeting notice ..... in 30 min", but on macOS it appears as "Meeting notice ..... now".

It appears that the notifications on macOS tell me when the alert is raised and *not* when the meeting is to be.  This is extremely confusing, and I think a bug.

Subsequently, the alert on the iPhone counts down to the meeting time, but the notification on macOS says things like "Meeting notice ..... 14m ago". If I get another alert (second alert say ten minutes before) this overwrites the notification in the notifications panel and the time is reset to "now".

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been driving me crazy so I called Apple. After a lengthy discussion and sharing my screen with AppleCare, support said they hadn't seen this before. They submitted a ticket to engineering and I'm waiting to hear back. I'll post an update when I do.

Comment: Hmm; "hadn't seen this before" sounds like they've just not been looking.

Comment: Apple's official response was that the behavior we're experiencing "is normal and expected". They suggested that we submit feedback on Apple's website and that's about it. This was absolutely never an issue for me before High Sierra, so it makes no sense to me. Why would I want the time displayed on a notification in notification center to be the time the notification popped up, not the time of the event? That's completely illogical. The next step for me is to reinstall the OS.